# Does an expression written x = <y,z> imply x = y = z?

Tags: set-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN0k1.jpg)

I don't understand how, if $x = \langle y, z\rangle$, and $y$ and $z$ are different and $x$ was a member of some relation $A$, $A$ could be a one place relation. This only seems possible if $x = y = z$.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is the ordered pair $\langle y, z\rangle$. It's a different sort of object from a number. It does have a set-theoretic definition, but that's not important here, as long as you keep in mind that it's just its own sort of object. It is not the same as asserting that $x=y=z$ and for most definitions of ordered pair (and axiom systems) this would not be possible.

Comment: I see, I’m confused about how this could be a 1-place relation though

Comment: If $\langle x, y\rangle$ is in R, then you're saying that x is related to y under the relation R, or xRy. The less-than relation includes $\langle0, 1\rangle$ because $0<1$.

Comment: Right, I understand how the relation works for the most part I think, but with your example, if <0,1> is a member of R doesn’t that make R a binary relation? Since it relates two objects

Comment: This is the definition of a binary relation, not a unary relation. The text makes that clear just above the cited portion. Not sure why it says 1-place below, possibly a typo.

Comment: @Newarc Here they are saying a two-place relation is a set of ordered pairs $<y,z>$.  Similarly a one-place relation could be a set of $x=<y>$ (an ordered singleton). An example of a one-place relation might be "is a prime number", so you would have $A=\{<2>, <3>,<5>, \ldots\}$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, and I’m sorry for the inconvenient question I’m about to ask but do you mind telling me what I missed to infer this? When he first says anything about a “1-place relation” I assumed he was talking about the example… I want to get better at reading these types of books so advice would be appreciated as I am also reading Endertons book on set theory

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a relation is essentially a set of *pairs* of elements from the underlying set. So in the given definition, $x$ is the pair $\langle y, z \rangle$, and we may also write "$yAz$" or "$y$ is related to $z$ under $A$".

For example, if we have the set $S = \{-1, 0, 1\}$ then we can express the relation "is less than" on $S$ with the set $A = \{\langle -1, 0 \rangle, \langle -1, 1 \rangle, \langle 0, 1 \rangle\}$. Notice that if $x \in A$ then we can write $x = \langle y, z \rangle$ where $y \in S$ and $z \in S$, but nowhere do we have $x = y$ or $y = z$.

Comment: At first I thought the same thing, but then how could this be a 1-place relation?

Comment: I'm suspicious of that name, since it is clearly a binary relation which anywhere else would be considered a 2-place relation.

Comment: Exactly, I also thought at first this would be considered a binary relation, but make no mistake he claims this relation is “1-place”

Comment: But he also describes it as a binary relation in the same paragraph

Comment: Huhhh? Where does he say this?

Comment: "Consequently we omit the modifying adjective "binary" in the following definition", i.e. the default assumption for a relation is that it is binary.

Comment: As far as I can tell, a one-place relation is approximately equivalent to set inclusion.

Comment: I don’t think that quote really makes sense in that context then… tbh I don’t really get the point of him “omitting the modifying adjective binary” in the first place.

Comment: It means that if he says "Let $A$ be a relation on $S$" then you can assume that it's a binary relation unless he says otherwise.

Comment: Ah yes I read your other comment wrong, but then still, how does the definition given make a 1 place relation? And I understand what you said about it being set inclusion this makes sense, which is also why I didn’t think it was some type of error

Comment: I *think* what he's trying to say is "This is the definition of a (binary) relation. If you think about how this can be extended to other $n$-place relations, you'll notice that the set inclusion we defined earlier could be considered a 1-place relation".

Comment: So could the example be interpreted as like A = {x}… at least if this is true it would just be an inclusion relation and as you said it would be 1-place